# ASP.NET Core 1.1.0 nulling values of Dictionary<string,object>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-1.1

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI Core 1.1.0 app that is not correctly serializing my responses when returned to the caller. I have an object with a property that is a `Dictionary<string,object>` and the values in the `Payload` dictionary are being nulled out when the response is returned to the caller.

Object:

```
ResponseObject {
  string ID {get; set;}
  DateTime Date {get; set;}
  Dictionary<string,object> Payload {get; set;}
  ...
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ResponseObject> Post([FromBody] ResponseObject request) {
  // Object here is deserialized correctly.
  // Do work
  ResponseObject response = ...
  // Object here has values in the Payload
  return response;
}
```

When the request comes into the app it is deserialized correctly into the `ResponseObject`, the app does some processing and returns that object back out in a modified form. The keys in the `Payload` dictionary can change in name and number. When the `ResponseObject` is about to return I can see in debugging that the data is in the `Payload` dictionary. Once the debugger leaves the `return` for the controller and sent back to the caller the dictionaries values are empty.

Based on this I can assume that the problem is happening in the ASP.NET Core app during serialization of the `ResponseObject` after the return. I do not want to change out the default serializer because everything else in the app works as expected. I know that deserialization and serialization of the `ResponseObject` using Json.NET works because the app does it flawlessly in other parts of the app. The only thing I can think of is that the default WebAPI serializer is using different options or is a different implementation.

What am I missing? Is there an option I can set for the serializer to get the values to show up? Or will I have to change the default serializer? Or is there some other solution I am not seeing?

Comment: Do you observe the same behaviour when the property is declared as an `IDictionary<string,object>`?

Comment: Yes I do. Same problem.

Comment: please raise an issue on GitHub https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/new

Comment: @AlexWiese interestingly I could not reproduce it when building a new sample project in order to open the issue. Must be something with our particular configuration of Web API. I don't have the time or motivation to figure out exactly what the issue is. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the return type on the controller to be a string and serializing the object myself directly. That way I have control over how the serialization is done and don't have to rely on WebAPI's magic beans to do it for me. It isn't the most ideal solution and not exactly what I wanted, but it works. The resulting controller that worked is below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> Post([FromBody] ResponseObject request) {
  // Do work
  ResponseObject response = ...
  // I am using Jil here, but you could also use Json.NET
  return JSON.SerializeDynamic(response);
  // return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you do not want to use Json.NET. Instead you can try the following

```
return Json(response);
```

Comment: No go. That didn't solve the problem unfortunately. Same exact output as before.